# 1 MS Access Query to Multiple Excel Files Based on Field Value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have MS Access query which I want to export to multiple excel files (.xlsx) based on a field value. In English, I have a query which contains all my customers but I want to create an excel file for each customer so that I can email each customer records to him/her later on.

I found a in this link code https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/export-results-query-multiple-files-access-vba/

This code works just fine with one issue. It exports the files as text files and couldn't convert to code to export excel files as I have little knowledge about VBA.

```
Sub DoExport(fieldName As String, queryName As String, filePath As String, Optional delim As Variant = vbTab)
Dim db As Database
Dim objRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim qdf As QueryDef

Dim fldcounter, colno, numcols As Integer
Dim numrows, loopcount As Long
Dim data, fs, fwriter As Variant
Dim fldnames(), headerString As String

'get details of the query we'll be exporting
Set objRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(queryName)

'load the query into a recordset so we can work with it
objRecordset.Open qdf.SQL, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

'load the recordset into an array
data = objRecordset.GetRows

'close the recordset as we're done with it now
objRecordset.Close

'get details of the size of array, and position of the field we're checking for in that array
colno = qdf.Fields(fieldName).OrdinalPosition
numrows = UBound(data, 2)
numcols = UBound(data, 1)


'as we'll need to write out a header for each file - get the field names for that header
'and construct a header string
ReDim fldnames(numcols)
For fldcounter = 0 To qdf.Fields.Count - 1
    fldnames(fldcounter) = qdf.Fields(fldcounter).Name
Next
headerString = Join(fldnames, delim)

'prepare the file scripting interface so we can create and write to our file(s)
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'loop through our array and output to the file
For loopcount = 0 To numrows
    If loopcount > 0 Then
        If data(colno, loopcount) <> data(colno, loopcount - 1) Then
            If Not IsEmpty(fwriter) Then fwriter.Close
            Set fwriter = fs.createTextfile(filePath & data(colno, loopcount) & ".txt", True)
            fwriter.writeline headerString
            writetoFile data, queryName, fwriter, loopcount, numcols
        Else
            writetoFile data, delim, fwriter, loopcount, numcols
        End If
    Else
        Set fwriter = fs.createTextfile(filePath & data(colno, loopcount) & ".txt", True)
        fwriter.writeline headerString
        writetoFile data, delim, fwriter, loopcount, numcols
    End If
Next

'tidy up after ourselves
fwriter.Close
Set fwriter = Nothing
Set objRecordset = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing

End Sub


'parameters are passed "by reference" to prevent moving potentially large objects around in memory
Sub writetoFile(ByRef data As Variant, ByVal delim As Variant, ByRef fwriter As Variant, ByVal counter As Long, ByVal numcols As Integer)
Dim loopcount As Integer
Dim outstr As String

For loopcount = 0 To numcols
    outstr = outstr & data(loopcount, counter)
    If loopcount < numcols Then outstr = outstr & delim
Next
fwriter.writeline outstr
End Sub
```

I really appreciate your help and support. Thanks!

Comment: this line right here is setting the export to a text file `Set fwriter = fs.createTextfile(filePath & data(colno, loopcount) & ".txt", True)`, So you will need to change that to an excel file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Access' [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet) method in a loop across a recordset of distinct customers. No need of generating text files, setting up arrays, or header loops. Be sure to create the query `[MyTempQuery]` in advance (which can be anything as its SQL is overwritten with each iteration. Also be sure to escape any single quotes in customer name.

```vb
Dim Db As DAO.Database, qdef AS DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [CustomerName] FROM [QueryName]")

Do While Not rst.EOF
    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("[MyTempQuery"])
    qdef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [QueryName] WHERE Customer = '" & rst!CustomerName & "'"

    Set qdef = Nothing
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "MyTempQuery", _
                  "C:\Path\To\Excel\Files\" & rst!CustomerName & ".xlsx", True
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: You are my hero sir! That worked like a charm! I will never be thankful enough as you saved me and my team 16 hours a month!

Comment: I was upvoting since yesterday and it wasn't showing. I just discovered the solved mark. Thanks again for helping me! :P