# 1 Access Query to Multiple Excel Files Based on Field Value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was looking for the exact same thing as the person that posted the following question:

[1 MS Access Query to Multiple Excel Files Based on Field Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520775/1-ms-access-query-to-multiple-excel-files-based-on-field-value/55523186#55523186?newreg=4c1c64e96f09484caf75796d653dcfc2)

This answer:

```
    Dim Db As DAO.Database, qdef AS DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [CustomerName] FROM [QueryName]")

Do While Not rst.EOF
    Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("[MyTempQuery]")
    qdef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [QueryName] WHERE Customer = '" & rst!CustomerName & "'"

    Set qdef = Nothing
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "MyTempQuery", _
                  "C:\Path\To\Excel\Files\" & rst!CustomerName & ".xlsx", True
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
```

...provided by @Parfait worked wonders, but since this access file is going to be used by several other people i now need the access to export the files in a sub folder of the same folder as the Access file instead of specifying an exact folder path in the code. Can anyone help me with that please?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: How do you want to determine the subfolder name to use? Where should that name come from? Does folder already exist? Is this a split database design?

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for replying! I actually managed to solve this on my own after looking at the documentation provided by Microsoft. :) I will provide the answer in a separate reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution to this. Basically i declared a variable as a string, and then used that variable to store the location of the access file. Then i created a folder inside that location and used it as the export target.

```
    Dim Db As DAO.Database, qdef AS DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset, expPath As String
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [CustomerName] FROM [QueryName]")
    expPath = Left(CurrentDb.Name, Len(CurrentDb.Name) - Len(Dir(CurrentDb.Name)))
    
MkDir expPath & "EXPORT"

    Do While Not rst.EOF
        Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("[MyTempQuery]")
        qdef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [QueryName] WHERE Customer = '" & rst!CustomerName & "'"
    
        Set qdef = Nothing
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "MyTempQuery", _
                      expPath & "EXPORT\" & rst!CustomerName & ".xlsx", True
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question right. Do you mean:

a) The Macro has multiple users and the regarding DB is located on a shared drive:

--> if that is the case: just change "C:\Path\To\Excel\Files" to whatever is the path to the shared drive.

---

b) if there is no shared drive and the the macro happens to be used locally: use "C:\Temp" as path. This folder exists on every Windows machine. With that you can be sure the path is found and the files can be saved.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for replying! I actually managed to solve this on my own after looking at the documentation provided by Microsoft. :) I will provide the answer in a separate reply.